# adding value to database via concat but in reverse order (last line will be first)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, concatenation

is there any trick to add the last input as the FIRST input via sql ?

In this example it add the last line at the end of `lastline` :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `mytable` SET `lastline` = concat(lastline, '$lastline') WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

this is the current order when add values to database :

```
Line #1\r\n
Line #2\r\n
Line #3\r\n
Line #4\r\n
```

I want the last line will add first (without read and write the content of `lastline`) so the progress will be directly on writing the line :

```
Line #4\r\n
Line #3\r\n
Line #2\r\n
Line #1\r\n
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to flip the order of your arguments here...

```
concat('$lastline', lastline)
```

Side note: `mysql_*` methods are deprecated, you should switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible. Then look at prepared statements with bound parameters, so you aren't so open to SQL injection.

Comment: I can't believe that it was that easy :) But Let me check :P

Answer (score 2):

You can simply change sequence in CONCAT:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `mytable` SET `lastline` = concat('$lastline', lastline) WHERE `id`='$id'");
```

P.S. Also escape your variables in query. i.e. with [mysql_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/ru/mysql_real_escape_string)